# Creting feed using signals in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, signals

Here i have defined a model to create a feed instance in 'models.py':

```
class StreamItem(models.Model):
  content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
  object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
  pub_date = models.DateTimeField()

  content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

  def get_rendered_html(self):
    template_name = 'streams/stream_item_%s.html' % (self.content_type.name)
    return render_to_string(template_name, { 'object': self.content_object })

def create_stream_item(sender, instance, signal, *args, **kwargs):
    # Check to see if the object was just created for the first time
    if 'created' in kwargs:
        if kwargs['created']:
            create = True

            # Get the instance's content type
            ctype = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(instance)

            pub_date = instance.pub_date

            if create:
                si = StreamItem.objects.get_or_create(content_type=ctype, object_id=instance.id, pub_date=pub_date)

# Send a signal on post_save for each of these models
for modelname in [Fest, College, Event]: 
    my_signal = dispatch.Signal()      
    my_signal.connect(create_stream_item, sender=modelname)
```

Then i have created views for getting the feed which are working just fine if I create the **StreamItem** object from the admin site. But, the **signals** part isn't just working. I am just learning about it, so, I don't understand where I am wrong. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`post_save`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#post-save) signal:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

for model in [Fest, College, Event]:
    post_save.connect(create_stream_item, sender=model)
```

Comment: Thanks! it worked :D. Could you please explain whats wrong with my previous code?

Comment: @Monique, As far as I know, [`dispatch.Signal`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/#django.dispatch.Signal) does nothing. It is used when you create your own signal.

Comment: Ok, thanks! Also, i want to make this feed user specific so could you suggest how i can make a StreamItem for each user?

Comment: @Monique, I don't understand what you mean. There's no `user` Fk field in `StreamItem` model accoridng to the code you posted. Please post another question with additional information.

Comment: Here is the link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20770360/creating-user-feed-using-django-signals